# How to determine if a process has booted and started to operate using C#'s Process class?

Tags: c#, .net, process

I am using the [Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?view=net-7.0) class to start a dotnet project from within C#. My start configuration looks like this:

```cs
processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
{
    FileName = @"dotnet",
    WorkingDirectory = path,
    UseShellExecute = true,
    Arguments = $"run --project {projectName}"
};
```

This project is starting a server which taskes a bit of time to boot. I want the program that starts this process to wait until the server has booted completely. Currently I am doing it by putting the thread to sleep, but this is not ideal and I would like to have a more adaptive solution. How can I achieve this ?

Comment: you may use Mutex ... when you are starting process generate guid create mutex with this guid and pass it to child process ... in child process release mutex when it started  .... in master process wait for release ...

Comment: I will look into it, it could be a possible solution. I was thinking that maybe I could use the output of the dotnet application somehow to provide feedback ? What do you think about that ?

Comment: Em you can't? As far as the operating system is concerned it looks exactly the same. The best you can do is pass a command line argument. Also why  use `dotnet run` why not just compile the project to an EXE?

Comment: maybe `EventWaitHandle` is better and also system wide

Comment: As @Selvin mentioned, a named mutex would work. I would be less sophisticated and just pick an explicit name (i.e. mycustomprocessisreadymutex). When the server is fully ready it would create the named mutex.  The monitor code can just try to open this mutex.

Since this is a server you're trying to monitor, another strategy might be to periodically send a message to the server and have the server respond accordingly. Once the server responds it's fully running, you can stop sending messages.

Comment: [this works in my code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JLMhUv) (and yes, I'm starting new process and wait in master process to child would be initialized) ... I could not make `Mutex` working ... with `EventWaitHandle` is easy as you can set initial state

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlXct.png ... I'm using `EventWaitHandle` because master process may spawn multiple child ... so I need to distinguish instances